# ruby -- string interpolation from file\pattern

Tags: ruby

i am using ruby 1.9.3 and i am trying to achieve string interpolation as follows:

- declare and assign a variable with a string value.
- read a file which has the string interpolation "pattern".
- do string interpolation.

for instance:

**`params.txt`**

```
"#{str}"
```

**`test.rb`**

```
str = "my string"
content = File.open("params.txt", "r").read()
puts("#{content}") #result in "#{str}" and not "my string", it returns the content of the file as is
```

how can i achieve string interpolation?

**UPDATE**
another example of what i am tyring to achieve:

```
str = "my string"
pat = '#{str}'
puts(pat)      # returns nil
puts("#{pat}") # returns nil
eval(pat)      # returns nil
eval("#{pat}") # returns nil
```

Comment: How is `str = "my string"` relevant?

Comment: That's what he's trying to interpolate.

Comment: It doesn't appear in the result.

Comment: By the way, `puts("#{content}")` is making things complicated. Why not write `puts(content)`?

Comment: @sawa, `puts("#{content}")` results in the same behaviour.

Comment: @MrRoth Yes. Of course it does. Why are you choosing a more complicated way to write it?

Comment: Is your update really showing what you are trying to achieve? It looks like what you got (except that the result is not correct).

Comment: You put `#{str}` in single quotes. That will void interpolation.

Comment: I was actually just thinking about this problem earlier today! :)

Comment: There are several answers here that are working for the given example. Your last update just miss the double quotes on #{str} as @sawa mentioned. Otherwise, it should work.

Comment: double quotation is basically string interpolation. i wanted to avoid the string interpolation on the declaration, since this is the "raw" data which is being retrieved from the file. for the file content given in the example above, i cannot produce the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "my string"
content = File.read("params.txt")
eval(content) # => "my string"
```

---

A preferred way for such purpose is:

params.txt

```
%{str}
```

test.rb

```
content = File.read("params.txt")
content % {str: "my string"}
# => "my string"
```

Comment: it returns `null` for me :(

Comment: I don't think so. `null` is not a valid Ruby object. The return value of `puts` is always `nil`.

Comment: `eval` is a ruby function that takes a command, invokes it on the underlying shell, and return the result. or something like that, so it should return `null`. try run such an example.

Comment: No. `eval` does not call the shell. By the way, I don't take commands from you.

Comment: take it easy, i had no intentions of being rude. please accept my apology if i even said something to upset you.

Comment: thank you, but it is not what i am trying to achieve. please refer to my update in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

This will be easier if you use ERB instead.

`params.txt`:

```
<%= str %>
```

`test.rb` should be something like:

```
str = "my string"
ERB.new("params.txt").result(binding)
```

[ERB docs here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html).

Comment: firstly, thank you. although i am familiar with ERB pattern, that is not what i am trying to achieve.